# Python error: input expected at most 1 argument, got 3

Tags: python, zelle-graphics

I am attempting to write a function to tell if two circles created by the user are intersecting or not. When testing the function, the points in the `main()` function give the error:

```
input expected at most 1 argument, got 3
```

When used in the `circleOverlap()` function, `distance()` works fine. The `distance()` function by itself gives the above error. I am not sure where to go from here:

```
def distance(point1, point2):

    p1x = point1.getX()
    p1y = point1.getY()
    p2x = point1.getX()
    p2y = point2.getY()

    dist = math.sqrt( ((p1x-p2x)**2)+((p1y-p2y)**2) )
    return dist

def circleOverlap():
    winHeight = 400
    winWidth = 400
    win = GraphWin("Overlapping circles", winHeight, winWidth)

    instruct = Text(Point(winWidth/2, winHeight-10), "Circles")
    instruct.draw(win)

    instruct.setText("Click to draw centerpoint of circle")
    center1 = win.getMouse()
    center1.draw(win)
    x1 = center1.getX()
    y1 = center1.getY()

    instruct.setText("Click to add border of circle.")
    border = win.getMouse()

    radius1 = distance(center1, border)
    circle1 = Circle(center1, radius1)
    circle1.draw(win)
    print(center1)

    instruct.setText("Click to draw centerpoint of circle")
    center2 = win.getMouse()
    center2.draw(win)
    x2 = center2.getX()
    y2 = center2.getY()

    instruct.setText("Click to add border of circle.")
    border2 = win.getMouse()

    radius2 = distance(center2, border2)
    circle2 = Circle(center2, radius2)
    circle2.draw(win)

    if radius1 > radius2:
        rds = radius1
    else:
        rds = radius2

    xDif = abs(x1-x2)
    yDif = abs(y1-y2)
    fDif = math.sqrt((xDif)**2 + (yDif)**2)
    if fDif <= rds:
        print("Circles Overlap")

    instruct.setText("Click anywhere to close.")
    win.getMouse()
    win.close()

def main():
    print("")
    print("Euclidean Distance Calculator!!")
    p2 = Point("3.0, 6.0")
    p1 = Point("3.0, 2.0")
    print(distance(p1, p2))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in your `distance()` function and a problem in your test code.  In your `distance()` function, the third line below is incorrect, it should be invoking `getX()` on `point2`:

```
p1x = point1.getX()
p1y = point1.getY()
p2x = point1.getX()
p2y = point2.getY()
```

This error was making your circles too small.  In your test code in `main()`, these lines are incorrect:

```
p2 = Point("3.0, 6.0")
p1 = Point("3.0, 2.0")
```

As you're passing individual strings where you should be passing two numbers:

```
p2 = Point(3.0, 6.0)
p1 = Point(3.0, 2.0)
```

Here's a rework of your code with the above fixes and some style changes:

```
from math import sqrt
from graphics import *

winHeight = 400
winWidth = 400

def distance(point1, point2):

    p1x = point1.getX()
    p1y = point1.getY()
    p2x = point2.getX()
    p2y = point2.getY()

    return sqrt((p1x - p2x)**2 + (p1y - p2y)**2)

def circleOverlap(win, instructions):

    instructions.setText("Click to draw center point of circle")
    center = win.getMouse()
    center.draw(win)
    x1 = center.getX()
    y1 = center.getY()

    instructions.setText("Click to add border of circle.")
    border = win.getMouse()

    radius1 = distance(center, border)
    Circle(center, radius1).draw(win)

    instructions.setText("Click to draw center point of circle")
    center = win.getMouse()
    center.draw(win)
    x2 = center.getX()
    y2 = center.getY()

    instructions.setText("Click to add border of circle.")
    border = win.getMouse()

    radius2 = distance(center, border)
    Circle(center, radius2).draw(win)

    radius = max(radius1, radius2)

    xDif = abs(x1 - x2)
    yDif = abs(y1 - y2)
    fDif = sqrt(xDif**2 + yDif**2)

    if fDif <= radius:
        return "Circles Overlap"

    return "Circles Don't Overlap"

def main():
    print("Euclidean Distance Calculator!")

    win = GraphWin("Overlapping circles", winHeight, winWidth)

    instructions = Text(Point(winWidth/2, winHeight-10), "Circles")
    instructions.draw(win)

    print(circleOverlap(win, instructions))

    instructions.setText("Click anywhere to close.")
    win.getMouse()
    win.close()

main()
```